# Which Star Trek character appeared on screen with the most different ranks?

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-rank

I don't mean due to inconsistency and prop goofs (like [O'Brien's notoriously inconsistent depiction](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Miles_O'Brien#Problematic_rank_history)).

But field commissions, flashbacks, alternate timelines, Q-manipulations, etc would be in-bounds.   It's about how they were intended to appear on screen.

Rank means Starfleet rank, or possibly rank in another contemporary alien quasi-military force.

Comment: I suspect the answer is Worf, who I think has appeared as Lieutenant JG, Lieutenant, Lieutenant Commander, and Commander.   But I'm not confident enough to post an answer.   Another candidate might be Chekov?

Comment: Other ideas:  
Picard:   cadet, ensign(?), lieutenant jg ("Tapestry"), Captain, and Admiral

Comment: Wonderboy Crusher: acting ensign, ensign, cadet and ???

Comment: Also on Worf, is ambassador a rank?

Comment: Also:   Kirk?  (including [tag:star-trek-reboot]-- cadet, ensign, captain and admiral ?

Comment: It's interesting that there are very few (none?) signficant characters who weren't commissioned officers.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: No, Ambassador is a *position*.  A rank is a link in the military chain of command.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Do the ranks have to be unique?  If not, then for kirk wouldn't it go cadet, ensign, captain, (commander in into darkness?), admiral, captain (post earth saving demotion in IV)

Comment: how many star fleet ranks are there total?

Comment: @CBredlow:   The question is about ranks held, not changes.   Otherwise every time anyone has a flashback or a temporary field commission or Q messes with them, they rack up the ranks.

Comment: @antony.trupe:   Well, I suppose: cadet, ensign, lt jg, lt, lt cmdr, cmdr, commodore (!), captain, and presumably several ranks of admiral.   And this is not counting non-commissioned ranks, provisionals, and field commissions.

Comment: Boy, I think I may really have messed this up be mentioning non-Starfleet ranks.   If there is support, I will split this into two questions and people can paste their responses into the appropriate one.

Comment: Also, let's not forget that in "[Starship Mine](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starship_Mine_(episode))", Picard held the rank of Barber.

Comment: I'm coming in late to this, but I'm certain that **Geordi LaForge** is the answer, and so +1 to @JohnP (and +1 to you for an awesome question).

Comment: @ThePopMachine : *"...Picard held the rank of barber."* It was a temporary field commission. ;-)  Whenever I watch that episode, I ask myself: how much would he really know about hair?

Comment: @Praxis:   Well, the fact a barber chooses to shave his head could be due to [the barber paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox)  -- no one else is any good, so easier to use phaser hair removal.

Comment: ... but this is a good point.   You'd think the bad guys could have just made him give a haircut to prove he's not who he claimed.   [This one](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/2/2b/Kiros.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/292?cb=20120611203128&path-prefix=en) needs one.

Comment: Answers should distinguish between the rank and position of captain.  JFK was a lieutenant (JG) when he was captain of the PT-109

Comment: Are these ranks as recorded officially by Starfleet, or just someone claiming/being told they're a particular rank?

Comment: JFK was in Star Trek?!?

Comment: Looking at the answers, especially the [Q one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99469/21137), I think this question also needs some clarification whether simply donning the appropriate costume qualifies for "having a rank".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:   Yes, there is a subtlety here.  Well, I did mention Q-manipulations were in bounds.  I don't think it matters from a practical point of view, except for Q, but I would accept any depiction of the character at a particular rank, presumably in uniform, assuming it was the intent of writers, not a costume goof up.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Ah, I had interpreted "Q-manipulations" as Q-caused changes to the timeline that would have characters end up (in that timeline, the regular way) in the respective ranks, rather than Q just switching someone's clothes, but all right.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:   I don't believe he ever switched anyone's clothes but his own.   Right?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Well, at least, he would switch the crew's uniforms for Robin Hood era garments in [Qpid](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Qpid_%28episode%29).

Comment: Note:   Troi appeared as a Tal Shiar Major.   This would count.

Comment: **Question:  Do any of the Star Trek games allow you to progress through ranks?**   I'm not normally interested in answers regarding games or EU, but it might be worth a note somewhere.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

According to the [Memory Alpha wiki](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Geordi_La_Forge), it would be **Geordi LaForge**.

> Geordi has held more ranks on screen than any other Star Trek character: he was an ensign in a flashback in TNG: "Identity Crisis", he was a lieutenant junior grade in TNG Season 1, a full lieutenant in TNG Season 2, a lieutenant commander in TNG Seasons 3 through 7 and the four Next Generation feature films, a commander in the illusory future of TNG: "Future Imperfect", and a captain in an alternate timeline in VOY: "Timeless".

That would be **6 ranks** (Ensign, Lieutenant JG, Lieutenant, Lt. Commander, Commander and Captain), and includes all ranks with the exception of the flag ranks (Admiralty).

Comment: This is going to be tough to beat

Comment: @johnP - Geordie is still the winner. One of Nog's ranks was illegitimate.

Comment: @Richard:   Can you explain?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Sorry. There should have been a link to [my answer below](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99480/20774)

Comment: So he was a Lt JG in season one and a Lt Cmdr by season three. No wonder Harry Kim is frustrated!

Comment: @ThruGog well, you just have to get past ensign.   Then you can breeze through the ranks

Comment: "That includes all ranks" You go straight from ensign to lieutenant in Starfleet?!

Comment: @TylerH - Yes. Naval ranks - Ensign, Lieutenant junior grade (JG), Lieutenant, Lieutenant Commander, Commander, Captain.

Comment: @JohnP Oh, commissioned officers. I was confusing "Ensign" with the basic enlisted "Seaman".

Comment: Geordi may have the most starfleet ranks in appearances, but  not total ranks including other military forces which clearly Worf has, which was the actual question, see Worf below.

Comment: @JMFB - Other than your answer has erroneous information, the last sentence states "Starfleet rank or other contemporary alien quasi military force". The objections to squire, etc. still stand, so if you grant the Captain position, that ties him at 6. The others are job titles.

Comment: **Note:** as established [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7384/what-exactly-is-the-standing-of-information-from-memory-alpha) Memory Alpha doesn't make a good primary source.  So the Memory Alpha quote is good for establishing when La Forge appeared as different ranks (verifiable).   But the "has held more ranks on screen than any other Star Trek character" isn't verifiable from that quote.   It's just an unsubstantiated claim.   See the conflicting quote (also from MA!) in [@Richard's answer of Nog](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99480/3823).

Comment: @ThePopMachine good point. And this is only Starfleet ranks. Your question also included contemporary military groups, klingon, etc. Which this answer does not include. So how about switching the correct answer to me! lol.

Comment: @JMFB:   There are some legitimate issues with your answer in the comments that you haven't corrected.     For example, Colonel Worf has no business being there.   Also, you seem to be stretching the definition of rank to include position, which, if we allowed, would expand the other answers too.

Answer (score 66):

I'm going to go with **Q**.

He appears as a Starfleet Lieutenant, a Starfleet Commander, a Starfleet Captain, a Starfleet Admiral as well as an RN Captain, a US Marine Colonel, a WWIII 'Drug Soldier', A Chakuzon Commander (in Q2) and a Napoleonic-era Marshall.

This makes a total of 9 military ranks held, four Starfleet and five others, albeit *all* are held illegitimately.

[image]

Comment: excellent point.   I really meant Starfleet rank.  Would you be offended if I clarified the question and we counted this as four, with four more as interesting side note trivia?

Comment: It was only a throwaway answer. I knew what you meant ☺

Comment: Brilliant answer; I would never have thought of Q!

Comment: @Richard:   Are you sure there were all illegitimate?   Maybe he went back in time, joined the Academy, studied for four years, and then served in Starfleet for 5-25 years, separately for each of those cases, while simultaneously manipulating the timeline to attain the rank and position needed for each of those displays.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: You *really* think Q would actually *attend* Starfleet Academy and take the tests -- as opposed to just finger-snip-altering the timeline to make it as if he had done so? It's much more in line with Q's character that he hadn't even bothered to do that much, and just donned the uniform, because -- who is to discipline him? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar:  It was just a joke to give Richard a hard time

Comment: the literally correct answer!

Comment: @ThePopMachine: If Q had spent 4 years in Starfleet Academy and 25 more years serving in Starfleet, then why did he bother annoying 3 TNG-era captains for 10 years in the name of "testing humanity's potential"?

Comment: @Ellesedil - For fun.

Comment: @ellesedil - I think we have to consider the possibility that Q is just a bit of a dick

Comment: A drug soldier is not a rank, and he did say contemporary which Napoleonic and US Marshall are clearly not. So that brings Q down to 5. That's the reason I put squire and some of the others as separate items to include in my Worf answer below as they are not contemporary military forces.

Comment: @JMFB - Clearly the drug soldier has a rank, we just don't know what it is. Also, the word "contemporary" was added after I'd posted this answer

Comment: @Richard kind of like my Worf answer that has "weapons officer," which was discounted in the comments section under my question. Clearly Worf has the most ranks. Yes it was added after mine as well which means squire should be included as well. I didn't write the series, just answered a question about it.

Answer (score 49):

Nog seems to hold an unfeasible number of ranks; On DS9 he holds the ranks of Cadet, Ensign and Lt Jg as well as a temporary promotion to Lt Cmdr on board the Valiant. He also holds the rank of full Commander as well as Captain, as seen in the alternate timeline in DS9: The Visitor.

That makes a combined total of **6** Starfleet ranks. The only main ranks we don't see are Fleet Admiral and Lieutenant

[image]

> While it is sometimes held that Geordi La Forge has held more ranks on
>   screen than any other Star Trek character, Nog certainly is a
>   competitor. Nog is first seen in his cadet's uniform in "Facets"
>   (albeit before formally entering the Academy) and retains this rank
>   until he is promoted to ensign in "Favor the Bold". In the series'
>   finale, "What You Leave Behind", he is promoted to lieutenant junior
>   grade. However, while serving on the USS Valiant in the episode of the
>   same name, Nog was assigned the duties of chief engineer with the rank
>   of lieutenant commander by acting captain Tim Watters. Furthermore, in
>   the alternate timeline of "The Visitor", Nog was seen first as
>   commander and then later on as captain. In all, there are six ranks:
>   cadet, ensign, lieutenant junior grade, lieutenant commander,
>   commander, and captain, thus equaling La Forge's number. - <sub><sup>[Memory Alpha: Nog](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nog#Background_information)</sup></sub>

Comment: Why was his rank questionably on the Valiant?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski - because it was a field promotion given by someone whose authority to do so at the time was questionable.

Answer (score 34):

**WORF**

***11 to 14 ranks***

**Starfleet:**

> Ensign (DS9/TOS Crossover: "Trials and Tribulations")
>
> Lieutenant (TNG episode: "Encounter at Farpoint")
>
> Lieutenant Jr Grade (TNG episode: "Evolution")
>
> Lieutenant Commander (TNG movie: Star Trek Generations)
>
> Commander (DS9 episode: "Way of the Warrior")

**Starfleet Parallel Universe**:

> Commander and First officer of the Enterprise-D (TNG: "Parallels")

**Mirror Universe:**

> Regent (DS9: "The Emperor's New Cloak") (both political and military position, commanded flagship of the Alliance) Look under heading *Mirror Universe*: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Regent

**Gowrons Klingon Defence Force:**

> Weapons Officer (TNG episode: "Redemption")
>
> Captain Worf  "...whom attained the rank of Captain (in Worf's case,
>   through the Klingon Defense Force) while under the command of Captain
>   Jean-Luc Picard." See paragraph under heading *Captain*:
>   https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_ranks

**Klingon:**

> Commander and First Officer IKS Rotarran (DS9: "Soldiers of the
>   Empire")
>
> Chancellor (DS9 episode: "Soldiers of the Empire") (The chancellor is both politically head of the high council and the military head of the Klingon Defense forces outranking all generals)

**Other Possibilities:**

**If you include Ambassador(s):**

> Ambassador to Qonos (DS9 episode: "What you leave behind")

**Starfleet TOS:**

> Colonel Worf of the Klingon Imperial Forces (Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country) (This is Worf's grandfather who is a
>   different entity, but so is a person in a parallel or mirror universe. He is
>   called Worf and has the same actor playing him)

**Q's Universe**

> Squire (TNG episode: "Qpid") (A squire is a military rank, it is the second lowest rank just below becoming a knight) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squire

So anywhere from 11 to 14 depending on what you consider a rank. Clearly Starfleet, Parallel, Mirror Universe, Gowron's Defense Force, and Klingon would count. Colonel Worf you have to decide if he's the same character, since it is in name & actor, but not the same entity. Ambassador does have power and was a promotion from commander, but is not necessarily a rank. He was chancellor albeit for a brief moment before he gave the office over to Martok. Chancellor is head of the Klingon Defense Force and highest held military rank. Squire should also be considered. In the Robin hood episode he was Will Scarlet who in many Robin Hood stories is considered a squire.

**Why I suggested you might think about including ambassador:**

> As high-ranking official representatives, Federation ambassadors have
>   powers to issue orders and special instructions to Starfleet starship
>   commanders. (TOS: "A Taste of Armageddon"; TNG: "The Host", "Data's
>   Day"; DS9: "The Adversary")
>   https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ambassador

**Klingon Defense Forces Rank Emblems**(added since people were questioning Worf holding various ranks in the Klingon Defencse forces):

> The rank system of the Klingon Defense Force bears some resemblance to
>   various Earth ranking systems. A ceremonial sash of varying design and
>   material is worn by commanding Klingon warriors to show rank and
>   status in society. The sash can be made of many materials, most
>   commonly of gold thread or silver metal, **such as those worn by Worf**
>   and Martok. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_ranks

**Klingon Defense Force Hierarchy:**

> The system of hierarchy aboard ships within the Defense Forces was
>   highly structured. According to one of their systems, one that
>   operated successfully for centuries, **the first officer of any Klingon
>   vessel** had the duty to assassinate his captain when and if the captain
>   became weak or unable to perform. It was expected that his honorable
>   retirement should be assisted by his "first". The second officer also
>   shared similar duties with his "first". (TNG: "A Matter Of Honor";
>   DS9: "Soldiers of the Empire")
>   https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_Defense_Force

**List of Klingon Defense Force Personnel:**

> WORF
>   https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_Defense_Force_personnel

(As a side note Worf is working on a project to do a new Star Trek series(God please make it happen) called "Captain Worf." So if that happens then the answer would change to 12-15 ranks adding Starfleet Captain. Here's a link to an article on it from this year http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2015/06/11/with-fan-support-michael-dorn-hopes-captain-worf-will-be-star-treks-next-frontier/)

Comment: Colonel Worf is Worf's grandfather; http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Worf_(Colonel). Ambassador is not a rank.

Comment: @Richard that's why I put 9-12 just depends on how you look at it. A squire was an assistant to a knight or in this case Robin Hood, so it's synonymous with rank but not necessarily. I just included the extras just because...but there's a solid 8 in there, maybe more depending how you look at it. Colonel Worf is still "Worf", just like alternate universe Worf is Worf but not the same entity, just same name, but he said to include anything on-screen so I included all of them with disclaimers.

Comment: Richard was at +7 and JohnP was at +13 when I posted this, it'll be tough to catch them...

Comment: I refuse to upvote this when it's got wrong info in it :-P

Comment: @Richard I'm an upvote whore, what wrong info you want changed? Actually your Nog answer that I wanted to ask but I'll ask later as I'm about to maxrep for the day.

Comment: My objections above remain. Squire isn't a military rank. Colonel Worf isn't the same person as Cmdr Worf, Ambassador isn't a rank.

Comment: Regent isn't a rank, neither is squire, chancellor or ambassador. All of those are civilian positions. Weapons officer is military, but again it's a position not a rank. That brings his number down to 5.

Comment: @JohnP Regent and chancellor being government positions doesn't necessarily preclude them from also being military ranks though.  As real-life examples, the [US President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_United_States) is the [highest miltary rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander-in-chief#United_States), and in North Korea the [supreme leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_leaders_of_North_Korea#Heads_of_the_military) is also the [highest military post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Commander_of_the_Korean_People%27s_Army).

Comment: @matts - For the US, Commander in Chief when used by the President is not a military rank. It is a civilian position. And no, the others don't preclude it, but it does not automatically connote it either.

Comment: @JMFB: 'Colonel Worf is still "Worf"' - isn't that like saying that Wesley Crusher has held the position of Chief Medical Officer because Wesley Crusher is still "Crusher"? Not the same entity as his mother, just the same name? In any case, Colonel Worf was a Colonel of the Klingon Imperial Forces, not a member of "Starfleet TOS".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I used disclaimers for those. Your example is not exact. Same name, Same actor, different entity. Just like the mirror universe is same actor, same name, different entity. I just threw it in. That's why it has a range and disclaimers.

Comment: When was Worf an ensign in the TOS crossover? He & Odo were disguised as civilian traders...

Comment: if you count a rank in the Klingon Military as separate from Starfleet military, than you could count 6 ranks or more. I am sure that Worf held other ranks (briefly) in the Klingon military

Comment: @JMFB : You have definitely made some solid improvements to this answer. Nice work! +1

Comment: I went back and watched the DS9/TOS episode. Worf is never shown as an Ensign - he and Odo spend the entire episode in either their regular uniforms or the civilian trader disguises. Also, he was never technically Chancellor either - after he killed Gowron the cloak was on his back for like ONE second, plus he refused the position and gave it to Martok.

Comment: @JMFB, you want to clean this up?

Comment: @ThePopMachine yes I will, when I have the time. My heart just isn't into this stuff right now, going through a lot. But I appreciate you pointing it out to me. I'll try to go through it in the next couple of days. Thx

Comment: @JMFB IN TNG All Good things, Future Worf is Governor of a  Klingon outpost on the border of the Neutral Zone. Is that rank listed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this and maybe someone can fill it out.

It's possible Wesley Crusher appears as six ranks.

It would depend on the following suppositions:

- Different levels of cadet count as different ranks.   The evidence for this: (1) cadets of different levels appears to be able to give lower-ranking cadets orders (see Red Squadron),  and Locarno refers to 'anyone under my commands' and (2) they wear different numbers of little black bars similar to rank pips, which apparently indicate their year in the Academy.
- Cdt. Crusher appears with zero or one pip.   I'm not certain of this, but I suspect it to be true.   It think there is a reveal of him in uniform after he hears he is admitted to the Academy.
- Acting Ensign and Ensign are different ranks.

If we accept those premises, then Crusher appears as:

**Acting Ensign, Ensign, Cadet grade 0 or 1, Cadet Grade 2, Cadet Grade 4, and Lieutenant.**

That is six.

Comment: Calling @Praxis?

Comment: What rank did he appear as in "[Parallels](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Wesley_Crusher_%28parallel%29.jpg)"? Full Lieutenant?

Comment: You'd also have to clarify your own question - While cadets have ranks among themselves, they equate to nothing in the "live" force. For example, the [Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force_Academy_Cadet_Insignia) has many ranks by year, but none of them have any meaning outside the academy, thus they aren't "Air Force" ranks.

Comment: @JohnP.   [Yes](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/startrek/images/0/0a/Alternate_Wesley.jpg)

Comment: Then you'd have to add Lt. jg to that, that was the rank he was in...Nemesis? It's all going to depend on how you view the cadet ranks.

Comment: Oh, and during his trial during the squadron death investigation, he's wearing a uniform with two black bars, rather than pips.

Comment: @JohnP:   I used the word pip to describe the things all the cadets wear.   You called them bars.

Comment: Ah. I was counting pips as the round collar insignia. Difference in meaning between a pip and a bar, but it's semantics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27391/discussion-between-johnp-and-thepopmachine).